# How do you horizontally center a bootstrap modal on the page?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to get my bootstrap modal to center horizontally on the page after it has appeared, but I can only seem to get the code to center it vertically. Here is my code so far:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            function alignModal() {
                var modalDialog = $(this).find(".modal-dialog");

                // Applying the top margin on modal dialog to align it vertically center
                modalDialog.css("margin-top", Math.max(0, ($(window).height() - modalDialog.height()) / 2));
            }
            // Align modal when it is displayed
            $(".modal").on("shown.bs.modal", alignModal);

            // Align modal when user resize the window
            $(window).on("resize", function () {
                $(".modal:visible").each(alignModal);
            });
        });
```

Comment: @greybeard fixed the question

Comment: Please add more detail to your question. What version of Bootstrap are you using? How does your markup look like? Are you loading all the required dependencies as documented [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/) (v3.3) or [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/) (v4.5)? Ideally, you should create a [mcve] making sure it reproduces your issue. In short, modals ***are horizontally centered*** in Bootstrap *out-of-the-box*. If yours isn't, you probably messed up the markup or are applying some weird CSS. Allow us to look into it.

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean center **vertically**? Because you wrote "horizontally" twice. 
If vertically: From [Bootstrap's documentation page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#vertically-centered) :

Add **.modal-dialog-centered** to .modal-dialog to vertically center the modal.

Comment: Sorry, I mean I already got it to center vertically but not horizontally.